# Pycharm Docker remote unittest debugging with invalid volume specification

Tags: python, linux, windows, docker, pycharm

I have the following problem. I have a project which I want to debug via PyCharm and a docker image via ssh remote connection to some server. For standard debugging it is no problem. It works!

Docker Desktop is installed on windows. PyCharm 2021.3.3 is set up. Windows Linux path conversion is setup in the enviromental variables. But when I start a debugging process of a unit test with the same docker image, I get the following error:

> Cannot run the remote Python interpreter: invalid volume specification: 'C:\project:/opt/project:rw'**

[image]

[image]

This also worked for me before the system got a fresh windows installation. So my guess is that the unittest docker process somehow uses another part of the docker engine where I do not have the permission to process the windows Linux path conversion? the "rw" of the exception is read, write, isn't it? Furthermore it seems like it totally ignores the configuration file because i set a path to k where i map my project to but it has the project dir of C: in the exception message

I also tried different dokcer desktop version and different pycharm versions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you provided, it looks like there is an issue with the volume specification in the Docker configuration for your PyCharm debugging setup. In the error message, the volume specification is shown as C:\project:/opt/project:rw, which is not a valid format for defining a volume in Docker.

To correct this issue, you will need to update the volume specification to use the correct format for defining volumes in Docker. The correct format for defining a volume in Docker is host-dir:container-dir, where host-dir is the path to the directory on the host machine that you want to mount as a volume, and container-dir is the path where the volume will be mounted within the Docker container.

For example, if you want to mount the C:\project directory from the host machine as a volume at the /opt/project directory within the Docker container, you would specify the volume as C:\project:/opt/project. Additionally, you can specify additional options for the volume, such as :rw to make the volume writable, by appending them to the end of the volume specification after a comma.